# Conditional processing in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Can I do the following in PostgreSQL:

```
WHEN (my_session <> admin)
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing123 () RETURNS VOID AS
   ....



   ...
   //end of function here
```

In other words, if `my_session <> admin` is `TRUE`, the function will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DO` statement for that, like this:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   issuper boolean;
BEGIN
   /* check if current user is superuser */
   SELECT usesuper INTO issuper
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
      WHERE usename = CURRENT_USER;
   IF issuper THEN
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing123() RETURNS void AS ...;
   END IF;
END;$$;
```